# jquery group array alphabetically

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I've been digging around for a while now and can't find a solution. I would be very grateful if someone could help me on this one.

basically I have a list like so:

```
<ul class="list-items" id="1">
    <li class="3"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnc-3d-computer-animation">3D Computer Animation</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnc-accounting">Accounting</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-accounting">Accounting</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/ncga-administration">Administration</a> NCGA SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/svq-administration">Administration</a> SVQ SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnc-administration-information">Administration &amp; Information</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-administration-information">Administration &amp; Information</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/computing-and-it/advanced-ecdl-word-processing-2013">Advanced ECDL: Word Processing 2013 </a> Equivalent to SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-advertising-pr">Advertising &amp; PR</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/care/award-alcohol-awareness">Alcohol Awareness</a> Award, Level 1     Equivalent to SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/animal-care/introduction-animal-care">Animal Care</a> Introduction SCQF Level     4/5  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/animal-care/nc-animal-care">Animal Care</a> NC SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/animal-care/hnd-animal-care">Animal Care</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/art-design">Art &amp; Design</a> SCQF Level     4/5  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/nc-art-design">Art &amp; Design</a> NC SCQF Level     6  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnc-art-design">Art &amp; Design</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnd-art-design">Art &amp; Design</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/diploma-automotive-accident-repair-principles-body-paint">Automotive Accident Repair Principles (Body &amp; Paint)</a> Diploma SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/diploma-automotive-maintenance-repair-principles">Automotive Maintenance &amp; Repair  Principles</a> Diploma, Level 1 SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="A"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/diploma-automotive-maintenance-repair-principles-0">Automotive Maintenance &amp; Repair  Principles</a> Diploma, Level 2 SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/nc-built-environment">Built Environment</a> NC SCQF Level     5/6  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/hnc-built-environment">Built Environment</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/ncga-business">Business</a> NCGA SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnc-business">Business</a> HNC SCQF Level     7  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-business">Business</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/introduction-business-administration">Business &amp; Administration</a> Introduction SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="B"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/ncga-business-with-esol">Business with ESOL</a> NCGA SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="C"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/nc-computer-arts-animation">Computer Arts &amp; Animation</a> NC SCQF Level     6  </li>
    <li class="C"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/introduction-construction-crafts">Construction (Crafts)</a> Introduction SCQF Level     4/5  </li>
    <li class="E"><a href="/courses/esol/pre-intermediate-english-for-speakers-of-other-languages-esol">English for Speakers of Other Languages (ESOL)</a> Pre-intermediate, Pre-intermediate     Equivalent to SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="E"><a href="/courses/esol/pre-intermediate-english-for-speakers-of-other-languages-pt">English for Speakers of Other Languages (ESOL)</a> Pre-intermediate, Pre-intermediate SCQF Level     1  </li>
    <li class="E"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-events-management">Events Management</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="F"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/nc-fashion-design-manufacture">Fashion Design &amp; Manufacture</a> NC SCQF Level     6  </li>
    <li class="F"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/city-guilds-level-2-diploma-floristry">Floristry</a> City &amp; Guilds Level 2 Diploma SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="G"><a href="/courses/automotive-and-construction/npa-general-building">General Building</a> NPA SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="I"><a href="/courses/computing-and-it/it-in-business-word-processing-and-presentations">IT in Business: Word Processing and Presentations</a>    Equivalent to SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="L"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-legal-services">Legal Services</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="P"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/nc-photography">Photography</a> NC SCQF Level     6  </li>
    <li class="P"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnd-photography">Photography</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="R"><a href="/courses/engineering/rya-day-skipper-shore-based-course">RYA Day Skipper Shore Based Course</a>      </li>
    <li class="S"><a href="/courses/care/supporting-people-with-down-syndrome">Supporting People with Down Syndrome</a>    Equivalent to SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="T"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnd-textiles">Textiles</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="T"><a href="/courses/engineering/thermofluids">Thermofluids</a>    Equivalent to SCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="T"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/nc-travel-tourism">Travel &amp; Tourism</a> NC SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="T"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/hnd-travel-tourism">Travel &amp; Tourism</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="T"><a href="/courses/business-and-management/nc-travel-tourism-with-esol">Travel &amp; Tourism with ESOL</a> NC SCQF Level     5  </li>
    <li class="U"><a href="/courses/care/certificate-understanding-end-of-life-care">Understanding End of Life Care</a> Certificate, Level 2     Equivalent toSCQF Level     4  </li>
    <li class="V"><a href="/courses/animal-care/city-guilds-level-3-diploma-veterinary-nursing-small-animal">Veterinary Nursing (Small Animal)</a> City &amp; Guilds Level 3 Diploma SCQF Level     6  </li>
    <li class="V"><a href="/courses/art-design-and-photography/hnd-visual-communication">Visual Communication</a> HND SCQF Level     8  </li>
    <li class="W"><a href="/courses/computing-and-it/advanced-word">Word</a> Advanced Equivalent to SCQF Level     4  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get all these list items and group them into arrays by letter/number, I can then count them and group them (A-C (25 items)) and display them in columns.

Any idea how to get these into arrays like:

```
var listGroups[A] = the list items.
```

I would prefer to group them off the first letter of the list item and not the class="A", but whichever way gets the job done easiest will do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want the list item tags inside an array arranged by group (class) right ?

Comment: take a look at demo source, maybe could help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stores each "category" in a different array (`myArray` will contain a bunch of arrays)
and then you can decide to retrieve entries with `myArray['A']` or `myArray['B']`, etc which will allow you to group them easily.

This method doesn't require you to add `class="A"`, `class="B"`, etc as it's retrieving the text.

Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    var myArray = [];
    $.each($(".list-items li"), function(index, value){
        var text = $(value).text();
        var firstLetter = text.charAt(0);

        if(!myArray[firstLetter]) myArray[firstLetter] = [];
        myArray[firstLetter].push(text); 
    });

    console.log(myArray);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/newblt123/G2hzW/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wish I could mark all these answers as correct! Thank you everyone for your swift, accurate replies, I am incredibly grateful!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with length:

```
var listGroups = {};
    listGroups['A'] = $('.list-items .A').length + 
                      $('.list-items .B').length + 
                      $('.list-items .C').length;
```

now if you log this:

```
console.log(listGroups.A, " items found from A-C"); 
// logs "28  items found from A-C"
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MuzJU/)

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if this is what are you looking for but try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/FDMaX/1/) :

**Jquery** :

```
var listGroups = {};
$('#1 li').each(function () {
    var liClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if (listGroups[liClass] === undefined) {
        listGroups[liClass] = new Array();
    }
    listGroups[liClass].push(this.outerHTML);
});
```

what i dide here is i created an array of all the classes in the UL (A,B,C.....)
and in evry one of them i put an array of the LIs that belongs to that class

Comment: **PS :** if you want replace outerHTML by innerHTML to get only the 'a' tags inside or use $(this).children('a').html(); to get only the text inside the 'a' tags

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to show your element grouping by its class. (in your html class is equal to the first letter)

In jquery you can do a multi class select in this way:

## css

```
ul li {
   display: none;
}
```

## JQuery

```
$(".A, .B, .C").show();
```

To get total group elements:

```
var l = $(".A, .B, .C").length;
console.log(l);
```

Take a look at the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2aj97/).

To show in column you have to adjust css or you can take inspiration from this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2aj97/2/)**.